# What should I do when 'more than one instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list'?

Tags: c++, overloading, sqrt

I get an error in my code in the for loop, `for ( j = 3; j <=sqrt(num); j +=2)`:

> more than one instance of overloaded function "sqrt" matches the argument list.

How do I resolve that?

```
# include <cmath>

// determine if number is prime
bool isPrime (long n) 
{
  int j, num = 0;
  {
    if (num <=1)
      return false;
  }
  for ( j = 3; j <=sqrt(num); j +=2)
  {
    if (num % j == 0)
      return false;
  }   
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What are your `sqrt()` functions? did you overload it? What candidates does the compiler show you?

Comment: `int j, num = 0;
{
if (num <=1)

return false;
}` Wouldn't this cause `isPrime` to return false every time?

Comment: @chris: Indeed. Once that's fixed, the following loop will return false for any number except 2.

Comment: @Mike Seymour, Good catch. That one will save a bit of headache later.

Answer (score 10):

Try:

```
for (j = 3; j <= std::sqrt(static_cast<float>(num)); j +=2)
```

What is happening is that `<cmath>` contains 3 different [definitions of sqrt](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/sqrt) and the compiler doesn't know which one you are trying to use.

Comment: Also, it should be `std::sqrt`, and probably `static_cast<float>(num)`.

Comment: There used to be a "using namespace std" in the code OP posted. I'll take the static_cast remark :D

Answer (score 0):

You have missed out a angular bracket in your code after the second function
Are you compiling it with -lm tag?

plus you need t typecast j as int.

Answer (score -1):

You need to write a sensible `sqrt` function. [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Square_root_of_a_number) is probably the simplest way to go. Also, don't call the `sqrt` function each time in the loop. Just call it once.

Comment: There are evidently already multiple `sqrt` functions available. Why does this person need to write another one?

Comment: None of them quite does what he wants. He could jam the round peg in the square hole, I suppose. But we're talking five or six lines of code to do it right.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: All of them do exactly what he wants; they're just not overloaded for the exact type he has. He could write five or six lines of code, plus a few dozen to test it, and hope that he's got all of that right, I suppose. But we're talking a single call to a library function to do it right.

Comment: A floating point square root function does exactly what he wants?